# Is there a way to disable Thymeleaf, or only enable for certain REST calls?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

For instance, I have a basic POST that returns an html called "result" using Thymeleaf. This works and is cool.

```java
@PostMapping("/greeting")
public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting) {
    return "result";
}
```

But I have another totally unrelated method, that does something different, and returns not a template.

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/otherstuff", headers = "content-type=multipart/*")
public Object otherStuff(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile dataFile) {
    // Totally unrelated stuff
    return resultList;
}
```

Naturally, I get an exception:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "/otherstuff", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

because I'm intentionally not resolving a template. Can I turn off ThymeLeaf for this method? My Rest API is multi-purpose, and it would be rather unhelpful if ThymeLeaf ends up disrupting the whole project.

Thanks.

Comment: You're probably looking for `@ResponseBody`.

Comment: hmm. Yes. That's it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you should use `@ResponseBody` annotation on your method.
That's all you need.